# After "Your home bed was missing or obstructed" in minecraft, I can't find my way back

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my creative world, I had slept in a bed to set my spawn point. Then I broke the bed. I then accidentally fell out of the world (into the void) and died. It said "Your home bed was missing or obstructed" and it respawned me somewhere random. Now I can't find my way back! Help!

Comment: You should respawn near the death point.

Comment: @thecodingmonster Where you died does not influence where you spawn. If you destroyed your bed you will spawn at worldspawn.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad. Did they ever change it? [See here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Individual_spawn) for the wiki page on the respawning

Comment: Well, tbh, all you can do is look around and find the place, really.

Comment: Thanks guys, but Arperum, how do I get to the worldspawn? And SaintSix_, thanks anyway but I have looked a LOT xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to go /Gamemode 3 and fly for like 100 blocks each direction

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm pretty sure it's more than 100 blocks!

Comment: IT WORKED! Wow, good job OnePvP. BTW, how far away was it.

Answer (score 10):

If it is a creative world, you most likely have not explored a lot of the land mass, which should make this a lot easier to find, but it should work in survival worlds as well.

By default, your chunks are saved in:

```
%appdata%\saves\<world name>\region\*.mca
```

By checking the file modify date, find the last file that was changed before you died, as this is the file in which your chunks are saved that you modified. You can then use the application named [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer) to open the .mca file. After opening, you will see the chunks that are stored in that file. The formatting is as followed:

```
Chunk [<i>, <j>]    in world at (<x>, <y>)
```

`<i>` is the internal X coordinate of the chunk relative to the mca origin
`<j>` is the internal Z coordinate of the chunk relative to the mca origin
`<x>` is the external X coordinate of the chunk based on the game coordinates
`<y>` is the external Z coordinate of the chunk based on the game coordinates

By putting the `<x>` and `<y>` in a [Coordinate Tool](https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/) you can find the exact coordinates, or you can calculate the approximate coordinates yourself by multiplying the numbers by 16. (where 16 is the number of blocks in the X and Z direction of the chunks)

*Please note that even only loading a chunk makes the game update the mca file.*

Comment: If you walked a lot before you died you'll find the chunks of your death, not the one of your bed, which should have an earlier modification date (when you left it). Also it will be completely useless, if you updated all the other chunks (probably even the one with the bed) on your way looking for the bed. There should be a more reliable way.

Comment: Using the same application (NBTExplorer) you can also go into each chunk and get a list of all the entities in that chunk, such as workbenches, beds, furnaces etc. It is a lot more work, but still do-able. If requested, I could try to set up a script/program/webpage that would go through the file to list all items.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good and I will try it, but one problem: Looking through the files to find the last one changed before I died. Two things: 1: When I try opening the files they are all in gibberish and completely unreadable and 2: I have been on that world looking several times and finding the one before I died would take impossibly long. Still thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Using the NBTExplorer tool you should be able to open the files in a readable format. Do you have the opportunity to upload the world somewhere? I will take a look at it. If you know some of the items you placed, it will make it a lot easier as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should have spawned near your original spawn point before you slept in the bed. go the general direction you went to build your house. If you remembered the X, Y, and Z coordinates, you could teleport there

Comment: I actually started building my things right where I spawned, sorry! I couldn't remember there coordinates, so I checked all my old screenshots to see if i had any with f3 up, but no. P.S. The world is in creative.

Answer (score 1):

If you built your house near spawn then you should be able to use a compass to re-find the spawn point. Also try /gamemode spectator as this will allow you to pass through blocks and see manually lighted areas easier.

Comment: Already tried the compass. The reason it doesn't work is when I fell out of the world, because I broke my bed it set a new random spawnpoint and that's where the compass leads to. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 1):

Use maps. With maps you can see the world from above. It will show you where blocks are and from there you can find your house. Click the Use button (right click) to activate it.

To make a map:

[image]

If you don't see anything that could resemble your house, then try expanding your map to show even more area.

This is the crafting recipie to expand/zoom-out a map:

[image]

Be aware though, even though it shows more area, it also zooms out. That means that it is less percise and can make you miss your house completely. There are four zoom levels in a map.

Here is a list of how many blocks a map can show:

-Zoom step 0 (default) shows an area of 128x128 blocks. 
-Zoom step 1 shows an area of 256x256 blocks. 
-Zoom step 2 shows an area of 512x512 blocks. 
-Zoom step 3 shows an area of 1028x1028 blocks. 
-Zoom step 4 shows an area of 2048x2048 blocks.

My info on the map was found at: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map . Please go there to get more info about maps. It has more information than I can give you in a quick answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and I will try this. Although I am not entirely sure 2048x2048 blocks will even be enough! :P

Comment: XD. 2048x2048 block is a HUGE area. It is 4,194,304 blocks total. Hopefully you can find your house.

Comment: Yeah, but I think it could be up to 10k blocks away lol